# How do I know the last sched time of a process

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, scheduling

I current run into an issue that a process seems stuck somehow, it just doesn't gets scheduled, the status is always 'S'. I have monitored sched_switch_task trace by debugfs for a while, didn't see the process get scheduled. So I would like to know when is that last time scheduled of this process by kernel?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note: the 'S' state generally means that the process is sleeping while waiting for some sort of input - network, user, disk, whatever...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *might* be possible using the info in `/proc/pid#/sched` file.

In there you can find these parameters (depending on the OS version, mine is opensuse 3.16.7-21-desktop):

```
se.exec_start                                :     593336938.868448
...
se.statistics.wait_start                     :             0.000000
se.statistics.sleep_start                    :     593336938.868448
se.statistics.block_start                    :             0.000000
```

The values represent timestamps relative to the system boot time, but in a unit which may depend on your system (in my example the unit is 0.5 msec, for a total value of ~6 days 20 hours and change).

In the last 3 parameters listed above at most one appears to be non-zero at any time and it I suspect that the respective non-zero value represents the time when it last entered the corresponding state (with the process actively running when all are zero).

So if your process is indeed stuck the non-zero value would have recorded when it got stuck.

Note: this is mostly based on observations and assumptions - I didn't find these parameters documented anywhere, so take them with a grain of salt.

Plenty of other scheduling info in that file, but mostly stats and without documentation difficult to use.

Comment: BTW, some nice related debugging recipes but not answering your question here: http://blog.tanelpoder.com/2013/02/21/peeking-into-linux-kernel-land-using-proc-filesystem-for-quickndirty-troubleshooting/